Automatic index of rows/cols when using GridLayout
I'm try to arrange cells in a GridLayout in such way that will match the orientation of the screen (vertical/horizontal)
Example
# .ts
mylayout = {
  rows: "115,115,115",
  cols: "auto"
}

# HTML
// the code is actually [columns]="mylayout.columns" [rows]="mylayout.rows"
<GridLayout columns="auto" rows="115, 115, 115"> 
  <Label text="0" row="0" col="0" />
  <Label text="1" row="1" col="0" />
  <Label text="2" row="2" col="0" />
</GridLayout>

The row= and the col inside every Label is hard-coded.
When I want to re-adjust it to match the screen, I need to flip the values like so:
<GridLayout columns="115, 115, 115" rows="auto">   <= rows/columns flip
  <Label text="0" row="0" col="1" />
  <Label text="1" row="0" col="2" />
  <Label text="2" row="0" col="3" />
</GridLayout>

This is a simple example of what i'm trying to do, and I can't use StackLayout instead.
My question is: how can I flip the values of row/col of each Label ?
